# How to properly and effectively hide Excel using Excel.Interop, or am I missing something?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

This is my first question, or should I say first help query, on this site so I'm going to be as clear and extensive as possible, don't fall asleep ! ;)

We're remodeling our old "application" which was an Excel template full of automation, printing, menu replacement, and DB recording, and all other stuff that made it a huge template (8MB) or at least to huge for keeping a record of each customer process this way (we have +200 new file a day and storage space is getting out of hand)

So I developed a WPF/C# application to only use the template for calculation as an empty shell, this way I just get to store a copy of each template version instead of a full file per customer, and store the data into SQL directly. I interact with this template with Excel.Interop, when calculations are needed I open the template, feed it with data, call a VBA macro to run calculation and then fetch some ranges containing resulting data to retrieve back in my application. All this needs to be/stay hidden from user (because CEO says so !!) and therefore I use "Application.Visible = False".

The actual problem is that what ever I do, and with what ever version on Excel I interact with (at least 2010 and 2016) I get what I would call a "buggy behaviour". When I launch several instances of my application, each of them have there own Excel instance running hidden in the background, calculation of each hidden workbook work flawlessly and independently. **BUT if I launch my application first, then open another excel file from explorer, Excel "steals" my hidden instance to open this new file and then my workbook becomes visible**... At first I thought that using Excel 2016 and the right registry key would solve this (HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options\DisableMergeInstance=1), but it doesn't work as I expected (it still steals on of my instance to show it, before opening the file in a new window, and if I hide application it hides it all)

My question (here it is) is whether there is a "best practice" to be able to interact with an hidden workbook and have the excel process "exclusively" used by my application instance ? Or maybe a solution from registry manipulation ... I'm running out of ideas ...

Thanks in advance for your time fore reading, and bless the one who will get me out of this !!!

Best regards !

PS : If calculation could get deported to server that would help a lot, but from what I understand ExcelService won't accept running VBA, so I'm stuck with Interop

[START Edit 1 - 2018/05/02]
Code sample of Excel launched in background :

```
private void launchExcel()
    {
        if (xlsApp != null) return;

        isReady = false;

        try
        {
            xlsApp = new Excel.Application();

            //Identification process Excel associé
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(xlsApp.Hwnd, out excelProcessId);

            ("OSEP Excel process ID = " + excelProcessId).writeToConsole();

            //Prevent Excel dialog
            xlsApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

            xlsApp.Visible = myApp.Configuration.mode_excel_visible;

            //Attaches event on Application.Exit, Application.DispatcherUnhandledException, and CurrentDomain.UnhandledException
            //On one of these event : dispose COM objects, and Kill Excel process
            this.CloseWithApplication();

            SheetSelectionChange((s, e) =>
            {
                WriteToConsole("SheetSelectionChange : " + e.Address);
            });

            AfterCalculate(() =>
            {
                WriteToConsole("AfterCalculate");
            });
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.writeToConsole();
        }
        finally
        {
            isReady = true;
        }           
    }
```

[END Edit 1 - 2018/05/02]

Comment: Can you port the calculations into C# and bypass Excel Interop entirely? Even if the calculations depend on Excel worksheet functions, you could use Interop to leverage those functions, while processing the data entirely in C#. This would reduce the template to nothing more than a rendering engine, to be used only when you want to output a specific client's information. Is there some particular reason these calculations have to be made using VBA?

Comment: Maybe I've missed the point here but when your application opens this `Excel Template`, can you not simply close it once the calculations are done? that way even if you open another excel instance, your workbook will not be visible

Comment: @ZevSpitz : unfortunately I can't, the process engine (which is coded in the template) isn't built by me, but by an excel expert for financial stuff that I could barely be able to recode myself, and AFAIK he is reluctant into becoming a full time developper and adapting to C#. We also came to the conclusion that with it's constantly changing criteria it would be better to have them evolve a part from each other.

Comment: @Zac : lauching this template takes 10s, which is not acceptable for us as calculation could be run many times after as many modification/adjustment the user makes to his simulation (and sometimes the user has to run it while the client is on the phone...), this is why i'm launching excel and it's template counterpart in the background of my launching application

Comment: Does it matter if you set the `UserControl` property of your hidden instance is set to `False`? Probably not, because if you are opening the hidden instance programmatically, it will already be set to `False`.

Comment: Also, could you post the code of how you are opening the hidden application and the workbook?

Comment: @ZevSpitz : I added the "launching" code. As a precision : there is nothing else than Excel that's required to stay hidden, my UserControl just displays result after the interaction but that's just UI concerns

Comment: Just thinking of a rather ugly workaround -- each instance of your program should open two hidden instances of the Excel Application; one  to manipulate this workbook, and one to be ready in case the user opens an Excel file from Explorer. This assumes that the latest instance to be opened will be the one hijacked.

Comment: @ZevSpitz I agree, that's ugly ;) But while I'm awaiting for a real and fine solution, I'm also working on an other not so ugly solution : making a "proxy" exe that would force new Excel to launch and bind it with all extensions... but that's just patching and I really don't like that